# iOS singleton viewDidLoad empty and on viewDidAppear not

Tags: ios, ios7, singleton

I created a singleton in ios7 like this:

**SharedData.h**

```
@interface SharedData : NSObject
{
}

+ (id)sharedInstance;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray    *list;

@end
```

**SharedData.m**

```
#import "SharedData.h"

@implementation SharedData
@synthesize list;

// Get the shared instance thread safe

+ (SharedData *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once = 0;
    static SharedData *sharedInstance = nil;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        //initialize
        list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

I always use this code to access this class:

```
SharedData *sharedData = [SharedData sharedInstance];
```

The problem is now when I switch the view in my viewDidLoad method the list is empty but in my viewDidAppear method everything is fine. Any ideas?

EDIT:
This is the code how I change the views:

```
SharedData *sharedData = [SharedData sharedInstance];
//clear feed and add new feed
[sharedData.list removeAllObjects];
[sharedData.list addObjectsFromArray:newList];

//show new gui
[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToMain" sender:self];
```

NOTE: I push from a normal ViewController to a TabBarController -> NavigationController -> TableViewController to display the list.

Answer (score 0):

How are you changing from one viewController to the other? Wich classes are the parents of your destination ViewController?,

If you are modifying properties of the view in the `prepareForSegue` method... you are forcing the view to load.

For example, you are setting the list of your singleton in `prepareForSegue`, but before setting the list you are modifying a property of your destination viewController. (doing something like `destVC.view = XXX` or `destVC.viewControllers = XX` if you are subclassing a UITabBarViewController...) Then you are triggering the viewDidLoad method , and it's executing before you have set the list to the correct value.

Or maybe you are seguing in two different places to the destinationViewController. And when the viewDidLoad happens, you  still have not updated the list on the singleton.

Here is the transcription of the chat with the poster of the question: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/55218

Comment: i edited the question with the code. i perform the switch with a segue. Where should i put the [self.tableView reloadData]? the viewDidAppear is too late. this gives an ugly transition

Comment: mmm... it seems correct, can you post here your prepareForSegue code? 
before doing the `performSegueWithIdentifier` have you checked that the list in the singleton is correctly loaded?

Comment: i don´t use the performSegueWithIdentifier method. It´s a Storyboard segue which is modal and flip. Yes is checked it. it is correct. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Hey! you have posted a piece of code in wich you are doing `performSegueWithIdentifier`... are you doing the segue in two different places?

Comment: i just use the segue once to flip the view. Here is my storyboard: http://i57.tinypic.com/2a8gj20.png . i think i miss something but i can't find it.

Comment: Yes, but are you seguing programatically (doing a ` performSegueWithIdentifier`) or are you seguing from a button pressed directly from the storyboard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55218/discussion-between-gabuh-and-user2630406).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the confusion between these two viewcontroller methods:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    //
 }
```

&

```
-(void) viewDidAppear{
    //
}
```

viewDidAppear is the method which is called each time your view changes but viewDidLoad is the method which is not necessarily called each time your view changes.

ViewDidLoad method is called when view loads for the first time, after that it doesn't get called until the views are removed/released.

**P.S**:  I suggest you to put the breakpoint in your viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear method and feel it. Your answer lies there.

Hope this helps you alot.

Good Luck.

Comment: i logged the count of the list in both methods. each method gets called but in the viewDidLoad the count=0 and in the viewDidAppear count=20

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i created a segue which went from the button to the next view. Because of this the viewDidLoad gets earlier called than the list assigned. I just changed the segue to go from view to view.